# Install crystal report for visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, crystal-reports

I developed a WinForms Application that use Crystal reports and Visual studio 2019.
 but when I moved my application to another PC without Visual studio installed,I tried install Crystal reports on the PC but got error:

"you must already have visual studio 2010,visual studio 2012,visual studio 2013,visual studio 2015,visual studio 2017or visual studio 2019 installed to proceed with this installation".

How do I install Crystal reports on the PC without installing Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not install **crystal report developer version** on deployment machine (PC without installing visual studio). So you have to install **crystal report runtime version** on second PC if you are not installing the visual studio on second PC.

These are some links where you can download the appropriate runtime version of crystal report for your application.

**link 1 :**
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/

**link 2 :**
https://www.parthpatel.net/install-crystal-report-runtime/

Comment: thanx you my Brother